# Is Peter encouraging believers to train in apologetics in 1 Peter 3:15?

Tags: 1-peter

1 Peter 3:15 (ESV):

> 15 but in your hearts honor Christ the Lord as holy, **always being prepared to make a defense to anyone who asks you for a reason for the hope that is in you**; yet do it with gentleness and respect,

What does Peter mean by *"[...] being prepared to make a defense to anyone who asks you for a reason [...]"*? Is Peter encouraging believers to train in apologetics?

Comment: Most people I have met simply understand that it is an opportunity to tell the enquirer of our personal testimony of the Lord and the hope that is within our breast. Peter was a man who caught fish for a living and then followed Jesus (literally, on foot) as the gospel was preached throughout Galiliee and Judaea. When did Peter ever 'train in apologetics' ? ? This question is profoundly impractical. in my view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 Peter 3:15 (ESV):

> 15 but in your hearts honor Christ the Lord as holy, always being prepared to make a **defense** [G627 apologia] to anyone who asks you for a reason for the hope that is in you; yet do it with gentleness and respect,

HELPS Word-studies

> 627 apología (from 575 /apó, "from" and 3056 /lógos, "**intelligent** reasoning") – properly, a well-reasoned reply; a thought-out response to adequately address the issue(s) that is raised.
>
> 627 /apología ("reasoned defense") is the term for making a **legal defense** in an ancient court. Today 627 /apología ("biblical **apologetics**") is used for supplying evidences for the Christian faith.
>
> [An "apology" in classical times had nothing to do with saying, "I'm sorry," but rather was a reasoned argument (defense) that presented evidence (supplied compelling proof).]

In fact, the English word 'apologetics' comes from a Greek word in this verse. So a strong argument can be made that Peter is encouraging believers to train in apologetics in 1 Peter 3:15. However, I do not think this is Peter's emphasis that he encourages every Chrisitan to be formally trained in intellectual apologetics. I think he used the Greek word rather informally.

Unlike Paul, Peter himself was not trained in logical apologetic reasoning. Peter's emphasis was on actions as he himself was a man of actions. One chapter earlier, he wrote in 2:12

> **Live** such good lives among the pagans that, though they **accuse** you of doing wrong, they may see your **good deeds** and glorify God on the day he visits us.

This is the context. This is the first line of defense: Live a good life. The 2nd line of defense is to be able to simply "give an answer to everyone who asks you to give the reason for the **hope** that you have" (NIV).

Jamieson-Fausset-Brown emphasizes on the hope and not on the apologetics:

> This verse does not impose an obligation to bring forward a learned proof and logical defense of revelation. But as believers deny themselves, crucify the world, and brave persecution, they must be buoyed up by some strong "**hope**"; men of the world, having no such **hope** themselves, are moved by curiosity to ask the secret of this hope; the believer must be ready to give an **experimental** [experiencial] account "how this hope arose in him, what it contains, and on what it rests" [Steiger].

Is Peter encouraging believers to train in apologetics in 1 Peter 3:15?

I think that would be an over-interpretation of 1 Peter 3:15. Peter was thinking in more concrete terms of living the hope and be able to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Note carefully what Peter is instructing here in 1 Peter 3:15 -

> always being prepared to make a defense to anyone who asks you for a
> reason for the hope that is in you

Some have a simple faith whose defense is simply that, "This is what happened to me and why I believe ..."

Others have a very complex faith that includes an understanding of physics, cosmology, technicalities in Greek and Hebrew, etc.  They have a great abundance of "evidence" for their faith.

There are others that are spread between these two extremes.

Now, Peter's instruction is to be ready to defend one's own faith, whatever that means, either simply or in a complex and complete way.

Which should one use?  The answer lies in the state of mind of the questioner - **Do not answer what the questioner is not asking!!!**  At the same time, we should be prepared to answer the questions that God sends to us via such questioners.

Comment: What if we come across an intellectually strong questioner? [For instance](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/81266/are-there-any-denominations-that-give-official-advice-on-how-to-win-atheists-for).

Comment: Given that Peter did not base his testimony on physics, cosmology, or technical linguistics, it seems to me that those fields (while potentially helpful) are not necessary to be able to exercise faith in the full, powerful, eternally transformative sense in which he did.

Comment: @HoldToTheRod - that is obviously true but beside the point here.  The point is that each person should practice what it is that make them believe and be ready to give that answer which will vary greatly from person to person.

Comment: @Dottard good thoughts; I think Paul would agree that God gives different people different gifts for the benefit of His work. I just wasn't sure if you were implying (perhaps you were not) that Peter's faith was simple--I do not believe it was.

Comment: @HoldToTheRod - I made no comment about Peter's faith.  I agree he was well informed as was Paul; both were excellent witnesses and greatly used by God.

Comment: @Spirit Realm Investigator, we only access God through faith (the certainty of things not seen). It's like reason (things seen and analysed) is on this side, then an invisible thing called faith, and after that God which is accessed by it. So anything that comes *before* faith are just tools to faith, people can question these tools, but ultimately only by faith(in His Son) we have access to God. What proof is there then, outside of reason? Well, if the outcome of performing what is said validates or not it's veracity.

Comment: If I tell you 'there is a man three blocks from here giving 10 bucks to anyone asking him'. The only way you can prove if this information is real or not is by going there. If there is such a man and if he indeed gives you ten bucks after you ask him, the information is truthful, it not, then what was said to you is false. But it was only proved through faith in what was said. Jesus said: 'Give and you will be given'. If you give and later you are given, then the information is teuthful. But you've had to have faith in what was said. This is how it is with all things of God.

Answer (score 0):

A believer and follower of Christ should at least be able to say how and why God is known to them. God does not hide himself from anyone, rather the unbeliever hide themselves from God.

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [Tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).